# Destroying Nested Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Good Morning,

I'm having an issues with nested comments. I have a partial which shows these but I want to add a delete snippet at the bottom of .each one.

Here is the partial:

_snippets.html.erb

```
<% @snippets.each do |snippet| %>


                <%= raw(snippet.content)  %>

                <% if can? :manage, snippet %>
                <%= link_to 'delete', book_snippet_path(snippet), :method => :delete %>
              <% end %>



<% end %>
```

**Here are my routes:**

```
     book_snippets POST     /books/:book_id/snippets(.:format)          snippets#create
   edit_book_snippet GET      /books/:book_id/snippets/:id/edit(.:format) snippets#edit
        book_snippet PATCH    /books/:book_id/snippets/:id(.:format)      snippets#update
                     PUT      /books/:book_id/snippets/:id(.:format)      snippets#update
                     DELETE   /books/:book_id/snippets/:id(.:format)      snippets#destroy
```

Here is the stack error, showing no route matches update?

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"snippets", :id=>nil, :book_id=>#<Snippet id: 4, content: "<p>YACHT!</p>\r\n", book_id: 4, created_at: "2013-11-15 09:12:20", updated_at: "2013-11-15 09:12:25", approved: true, user_id: 1>, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I know it's probably something stupid I'm missing but would really like some help figuring this one out.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `book_id` . You routes says

```
DELETE   /books/:book_id/snippets/:id(.:format)
```

needs a book_id in path. So need to pass @book object as well in the arguments.

```
            <%= raw(snippet.content)  %>

            <% if can? :manage, snippet %>
            <%= link_to 'delete', book_snippet_path(@book, snippet), :method => :delete %>
          <% end %>
```

Comment: I knew it was something silly I was missing. I take it you have to pass the object all the time with nested comments. Out if interest is there a DRYer way to do this?